# Can an abstract class be embedded in another class?

Tags: orientdb

The documentation says

> Abstract classes are essential to support Object Orientation without the typical spamming of the database with always empty auto-created clusters.

But it also says

> A class that can't have instances

However, I would like to embed a list class B in class A, not have class A inherit from the abstract class B. Is this allowed?
Example:

```
enter code here
propVal {
  locType : ""
  eleName : ""
  ...
  values :[valueStamp]
}

valueStamp {
  value : any,
  stamp : actionStamp
}

actionStamp{
 // various attributes that say who, when, where change was made
}
```

Is used in many classes keeping track of changes to various fields.
They will never be used stand alone, but can't inherit because they can be used more than once in a class
Sample parent class

```
classA{
    helperAId:"",
    helperAProps : embeddedList of PropVals,
    helperBId : "",
    helperBProps : embeddedList of PropVals
}
```

Comment: please give an example of what you want to achieve. Best is to give a (pseudo) code example.

Comment: Please do not answer in the comments but update (edit) your question

Answer (score 1):

- Important: The class hierarchy supported by OrientDB is similar to OO principles as implemented by popular languages like Java. However, **it is not the same**, so there are important differences!
- Yes you can embed a (list of) class(es) of type `B` in a class type `A`. This is perfectly valid and a much used construct. This is done using the EMBEDDED type.
- OrientDB does not support the concept of interfaces or mixin's, just classes and abstract classes. So a class can only inherent (extend) a single parent class. In your use case I would create an abstract `ActionStamp` class (or whatever you name it) and let your other classes extend it.The `B` and `A` classes can both extend this `ActionStamp` class

So, using your example:

`CREATE ABSTRACT CLASS propVal
...
CREATE CLASS A
CREATE PROPERTY A.helperAProps EMBEDDEDLIST propVal
...`

Comment: Thank you. But I would like to embed an abstract class, not a class that has inherited from an abstract class.

Comment: in the above example I need PropVal, ValueStamp, ActionStamp to all be abstract and embed PropVal >1 times in ClassA so inheritence won't work.